# if image link is error,how to set local image in nativescript with angular

Tags: nativescript-angular

if image link is error,how to set local image  in nativescript with angular

it shows 
 Error in downloadBitmap - java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://app.krishnabhavanfoods.in/get_image/5b168010a237740652193d06

how can i set default local image if image src is error.

Comment: please share html snippet.

Comment: share html code to